# $f(xy)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{x+y}$ Prove that $f$ is identically equal to $0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. also $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ and $x+y\not=0$.

**My attempt:**
 I restated it as

$a[x^2 y^2 (\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}-\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{x^2})] +
 b[xy(x+y-\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x})] + c [x+y-2]=0$

because of $f(xy) - \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{x+y}=0$

(we know that $f$ is identically equal to $0$)

and later tried to prove that

$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}-\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$

$x+y-\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}$

$x+y-2$

are all equal to 1. I eventually got to that

$x^2 -2x -1,5 =0$ And i don't like this

Later I tried ;

$\frac{a(x^2+y^2)+b(x+y)+2c}{x+y} = \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}$

because if

$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$

$xy=0$ but that implies that $c$ is equal to $0$ too. Both of my trials are propably wrong.

Comment: $f$ identically equal to $0$ satisfies the functional equation, so you seem to be asking the impossible. Did you mean *"Prove that there exists an $f$ satisfying this functional equation which isn't identically equal to $0$"*? Also, what do you mean by $f : R ->$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor  yeah thanks for remark I made a mistake in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=1$

$f(x)(x+1)=f(x)+f(1)$ Hence $$f(x)=\frac{f(1)}{x}$$

You can verify that : $$f(xy)=\frac{f(1)}{xy}=\frac{\frac{f(1)}{x}+\frac{f(1)}{y}}{x+y}$$

As Peter Taylor explained in the comment :

$$f(0)=f(1)+f(0)$$

So if you want $f$ to be defined on $\mathbb R$, you need to have $f(1)=0$. Hence $$\forall x\neq 0\quad f(x)=\frac{f(1)}{x}=0$$

Then $\forall x\neq 0\quad x.f(0)=f(0)$ implies $f(0)=0$

Comment: This answer  does not hold anymore - there was a mistake in my question ,it should be "prove that $f$ is identically equal to $0$"

Comment: @II It is a valid proof that $f$ does not have to be $0$. So you can't prove that $f$ is $0$.

Comment: I think the missing step is that since $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(0)$ must be defined. Then $\forall x \ne 0: f(0) = \frac{f(x)+f(0)}{x}$, and in particular $f(0) = f(1)+f(0)$ whence $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : you are right indeed !

Comment: @II Sorry I fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Setting $(x, y) = (1, 0)$ gives $f(1) = f(1) + f(0)$; that is, $f(0) = 0$. For $x\not =0$, setting $y = 0$ in the given equation shows that $(f(x) + f(0))/x = f(x)/x$ vanishes; that is, $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Neat.  $\forall x ~ f(x) = f(x)/x$ can only be satisfied by $f(x) = 0$.